# error no master data blocks are available

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I try create project but I have get to proplem
 in form builder when I click right and chose data block  then chose table and click in add realshenshep I get these error said 'error no master data blocks are available'
Please help me
I am waiting to reply me
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Wizard to create relationship between master and detail block, underlying tables have to be related - master table has to have a primary key, and it has to be referenced by detail table's foreign key.

Forms is capable of detecting that and, if it exists, can create the relationship.

Otherwise, if there's no such a relation between those tables, you'll have to create it manually.

**[EDIT]**

How to create a foreign key?

```
SQL> create table master
  2    (id    number,
  3     name  varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table detail
  2    (id   number,
  3     idm  number,
  4     datum date
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> -- create a primary key on the master table
SQL> alter table master add constraint pk_mas primary key (id);

Table altered.

SQL> -- create a foreign key on the detail table
SQL> alter table detail add constraint fk_det_mas foreign key (idm)
  2    references master (id);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

As of manually creating a relationship: put the join condition in there, such as

```
detail.idm = master.id
```

Comment: So why cuase these error said 'error no master data blocks are available and what do you to solve proplem to order do not come error

Comment: I told you what caused it (no foreign key constraint). I also told you what to do if you want to fix it (create a foreign key constraint, or - do it manually).

Comment: I edited my message and added code which shows how to do that. Have a look, please.

Comment: if you do detales before master is these cause proplem error ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, as far as I can tell. Both blocks have to exist, and then you can add a relationship.

Comment: If you talk arabic ?

Comment: No, I don't, sorry.

Comment: How to know table master or detail by sql

Comment: As you're developing a form, you *should* already know which table is a master, and which one is a detail. As schemas can be very complex, without an ER diagram it is kind of difficult to find what you asked, as tables can be referenced back and forth with many other tables.